# Show that the following $x_n$ is a contractive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

If $x_1 > 0$, and $x_{n+1} = (2 + x_n)^{-1} \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $x_n$ is contractive.

I tried proving this directly using the definition

$|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| = C\ |x_{n+1} - x_{n}|$ where $0<C<1$.

All I've got is a big mess of a working, I feel that I've miss some important observation here.

Any help or insight on is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mean value theorem. Call $f: [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ the map $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+2}$. It is quite simple to verify that $|f'(x)| < 1/4$ for all $x>0$.

So $$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}| = |f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)| = |f'( \xi)||x_{n+1}-x_n| \le \frac 14 |x_{n+1}-x_n|$$

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I'm not really familiar with the mean value theorem. Although from your working, I understand what you are trying to achieve, my only query is that what does the zeta symbol mean ?

Comment: Well, if you were familiar with MVT, you should recognize $\xi$ as a special element inside the interval $[x_n , x_{n+1}]$ (or $[x_{n+1}, x_n]$) such that the statement of the theorem holds.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem . I use $x_n , x_{n+1}$ as the role of $a,b$, and $\xi$ as the role of $c$. It is not important to know exactly the value of $\xi$, though.